# wordpress theme install failing

Tags: themes, permissions

I am trying to install wordpress theme on my site, but is failing with message 
`Could not copy file. catch-responsive/404.php`

Folder permissions are as -

- ftp user is owner of the whole wordpress folder
- permissions are set as 755 for the wordpress folder
- When I start theme installation, it downloads into upgrade folder correctly but then i stops after the message above mentioned.

**I am able to upload themes manually with same ftp account**

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to upload the theme manually via FTP? You can upload the zip file and then create a PHP script to unzip it.

Comment: Yes I tried manuallyl uploading with ftp account (which i am trying for wordpress) and its working fine

Comment: OK, so if it is working fine, what's the problem?

Comment: I am not able to install automatically via wordpress, I mean from ftp I can install but from wordpress itself i can't

Comment: Is it possible that the `upload_max_filesize` PHP settings is set to a value lower than the file's size?

Comment: Its set to 20MB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37750/discussion-between-codeomnitrix-and-yoav-kadosh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was, that the *FTP* user does not equal the *Apache* / webserver user. I just had to (recursively) own the wordpress directory `/var/www` for the `www-data`/webserver user:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

[Please refer to this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/520634/giving-ownership-of-the-directory-to-the-apache-user) for further info about the owner of a directory.